# Upgrading to MySQL 5.5 from 5.0 looks broken

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, linux, mysql-5.0

I was using SLES SP3, and had earlier MySQL `5.0.67`. I upgraded it to `5.5.48` (available with the CD) after upgrading my OS to SP4.

I edited the /etc/my.cnf file, and replaced `skip-locking` to `skip-external-locking` and commented out `skip-innodb`

Post that, i had run `mysql_upgrade`.
The MySQL is started, and i can see the database, but several issues:

1) There is a strange `mysql#50#.tmp` table created, which when i saw in the data directory, looked to be an empty .tmp directory due to which it was showing.

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| #mysql50#.tmp      |
| InDexSql           |
| cifs               |
| ifm                |
| mirthdb            |
| mysql              |
| sn                 |
| test               |
+--------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

2) mysql_upgrade is failing in command prompt:

```
sles11sp3-116:/opt/mysql/data # mysql_upgrade
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

3) The mysql_error_log shows lot of errors:

```
160502 05:24:48 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/mysql/data
160502  5:24:48 [Warning] option 'general_log': boolean value '/var/log/mysqld.log' wasn't recognized. Set to OFF.
160502  5:24:48 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full na
me instead.


160502  5:27:43 [Warning] 'THREAD_CONCURRENCY' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
160502  5:27:43 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.43-log) starting as process 6716 ...
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
160502  5:27:43 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
160502  5:27:43 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160502  5:27:43 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160502  5:27:43 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
160502  5:27:43 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160502  5:27:43 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160502  5:27:43 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160502  5:27:43 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: 127 rollback segment(s) active.
160502  5:27:44  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160502  5:27:45 InnoDB: 5.5.43 started; log sequence number 43655
160502  5:27:45 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
160502  5:27:45 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
160502  5:27:45 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] Missing system table mysql.proxies_priv; please run mysql_upgrade to create it
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_current' has the wrong structure
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_history' has the wrong structure
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_history_long' has the wrong structure
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_consumers' has the wrong structure
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_instruments' has the wrong structure
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_timers' has the wrong structure
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'performance_timers' has the wrong structure
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'threads' has the wrong structure
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_instance' has the wrong structure
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_instance' has the wrong structure
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'mutex_instances' has the wrong structure
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'rwlock_instances' has the wrong structure
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'cond_instances' has the wrong structure
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_instances' has the wrong structure
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] Column count of mysql.db is wrong. Expected 22, found 20. Created with MySQL 50067, now running 50543. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this erro
r.
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] mysql.user has no `Event_priv` column at position 29
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] Cannot open mysql.event
160502  5:27:45 [ERROR] Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
160502  5:27:45 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.43-log'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  SUSE MySQL package
```

Can someone help me to know, what exactly i am missing?

Here is my.cnf file:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8
#password       = your_password
port            = 3306
socket          = /tmp/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
general-log = /var/log/mysqld.log
log-error = /var/log/mysqld.error.log
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 1024M
tmpdir = /opt/mysql/temp
max_connections = 500
key_buffer = 4096M
datadir         = /opt/mysql/data
user            = mysql
port            = 3306
socket          = /tmp/mysql.sock
#skip-locking
skip-external-locking

max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M

thread_cache = 8
query_cache_size = 32M
# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
thread_concurrency = 4
#skip-innodb


# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
#
#skip-networking

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id       = 1


[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Comment: Maybe you should have used 5.1 as an intermediate step in the update, going over multiple versions at once is not supported iirc. Do you have a backup of your datadir before the `mysql_upgrade`? The best way would be to revert to 5.0, dump everything to sql, install 5.5 (or maybe newer now when 5.7 is out) and reload the dump.

Comment: @jkavalik I just now answered to my own question, but need to understand, as what was wrong in the old my.cnf file.

Answer (score 1):

The problems got removed, when i swapped the my.cnf file, with a highly simplified version of it, which was earlier present in a machine, having MySQL 5.6.

So possibly the issue was with my.cnf file.

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

[mysqld]
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
max_connections = 500
#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#
# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
#datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
datadir=/opt/mysql/data

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# Recommended in standard MySQL setup
#sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

After swapping the above my.cnf file, even the mysql_upgrade worked.

```
sles11sp3-116:/tmp # mysql_upgrade -uroot -pinsite3
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
Running 'mysqlcheck with default connection arguments
Running 'mysqlcheck with default connection arguments
InDexSql.MasterImageSql                            OK
InDexSql.Patient                                   OK
InDexSql.commit                                    OK
InDexSql.orphan                                    OK
InDexSql.pfetch_sch                                OK
ifm.AttributesTable                                OK
ifm.ChunkTable                                     OK
ifm.FileTable                                      OK
ifm.LinksTable                                     OK
ifm.LocalStorageTable                              OK
ifm.PartitionTable                                 OK
ifm.SystemTable                                    OK
ifm.VersionsTable                                  OK
mirthdb.ALERT                                      OK
mirthdb.CHANNEL                                    OK
mirthdb.CODE_TEMPLATE                              OK
mirthdb.CONFIGURATION                              OK
mirthdb.D_CHANNELS                                 OK
mirthdb.EVENT                                      OK
mirthdb.PERSON                                     OK
mirthdb.PERSON_PASSWORD                            OK
mirthdb.PERSON_PREFERENCE                          OK
mirthdb.SCHEMA_INFO                                OK
mirthdb.SCRIPT                                     OK
mysql.columns_priv                                 OK
mysql.db                                           OK
mysql.func                                         OK
mysql.help_category
error    : Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `help_category`" or dump/reload to fix it!
mysql.help_keyword
error    : Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `help_keyword`" or dump/reload to fix it!
mysql.help_relation                                OK
mysql.help_topic
error    : Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `help_topic`" or dump/reload to fix it!
mysql.host                                         OK
mysql.proc
error    : Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `proc`" or dump/reload to fix it!
mysql.procs_priv                                   OK
mysql.tables_priv                                  OK
mysql.time_zone                                    OK
mysql.time_zone_leap_second                        OK
mysql.time_zone_name
error    : Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `time_zone_name`" or dump/reload to fix it!
mysql.time_zone_transition                         OK
mysql.time_zone_transition_type                    OK
mysql.user                                         OK
sn.db_hosts                                        OK
sn.facility                                        OK
sn.filter                                          OK
sn.studyqueue                                      OK
sn.viewer                                          OK

Repairing tables
mysql.help_category                                OK
mysql.help_keyword                                 OK
mysql.help_topic                                   OK
mysql.proc                                         OK
mysql.time_zone_name                               OK
Running 'mysql_fix_privilege_tables'...
WARNING: NULL values of the 'character_set_client' column ('mysql.proc' table) have been updated with a default value (utf8). Please verify if necessary.
WARNING: NULL values of the 'collation_connection' column ('mysql.proc' table) have been updated with a default value (utf8_general_ci). Please verify if necessary.
WARNING: NULL values of the 'db_collation' column ('mysql.proc' table) have been updated with default values. Please verify if necessary.
OK
```

As directed by mysql_upgrade, i manually invoked "Repair Table" after that.

```
mysql> REPAIR TABLE `help_category`;
+---------------------+--------+----------+----------+
| Table               | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+---------------------+--------+----------+----------+
| mysql.help_category | repair | status   | OK       |
+---------------------+--------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> REPAIR TABLE `help_keyword`;
+--------------------+--------+----------+----------+
| Table              | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+--------------------+--------+----------+----------+
| mysql.help_keyword | repair | status   | OK       |
+--------------------+--------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> REPAIR TABLE `help_topic`;
+------------------+--------+----------+----------+
| Table            | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+------------------+--------+----------+----------+
| mysql.help_topic | repair | status   | OK       |
+------------------+--------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> REPAIR TABLE `proc`;
+------------+--------+----------+----------+
| Table      | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+------------+--------+----------+----------+
| mysql.proc | repair | status   | OK       |
+------------+--------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> REPAIR TABLE `time_zone_name`;
+----------------------+--------+----------+----------+
| Table                | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+----------------------+--------+----------+----------+
| mysql.time_zone_name | repair | status   | OK       |
+----------------------+--------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```